# Read a Nfc Tag when app is started or resumed

Tags: android, nfc

In my Xamarin Forms android app I receive and read a nfc tag. The below code works fine when the app is opened and focused.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity,
    NfcAdapter.IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback, NfcAdapter.ICreateNdefMessageCallback
{
    private NfcAdapter _nfcAdapter;
    const string _appModePrefix = "@AppMode";
    const string _package = "com.companyname.nfc";

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    _nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);            

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    LoadApplication(new App());
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    if (_nfcAdapter != null && _nfcAdapter.IsEnabled && _nfcAdapter.IsNdefPushEnabled)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, GetType()).AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        _nfcAdapter.EnableForegroundDispatch
        (
            this,
            PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0),
            new[] { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered) },
            new String[][] {
                new string[] {
                        NFCTechs.Ndef
                    },
                    new string[] {
                        NFCTechs.MifareClassic,
                    },
            }
        );

        _nfcAdapter.SetOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
        _nfcAdapter.SetNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
    }
}

public void OnNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent e)
{

}

public NdefMessage CreateNdefMessage(NfcEvent e)
{            
    byte[] mimeBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("application/{0}",_package));
    byte[] id = new byte[] { 1, 3, 3, 7 };
    string appMode = "1";
    string appId = "826F3361-2E93-4378-A6B9-33D2B6087246";
    byte[] payload = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}|{2}", _appModePrefix, appMode, appId));
    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
            NdefRecord.CreateApplicationRecord(_package),                    
            new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TnfMimeMedia, mimeBytes, id, payload),                                        
    });
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();

    if (_nfcAdapter != null && _nfcAdapter.IsEnabled && _nfcAdapter.IsNdefPushEnabled)
        _nfcAdapter.DisableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent.Action == NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered || intent.Action == NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered)
    {
        var rawMessages = intent.GetParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraNdefMessages);

        if (rawMessages == null)
            return;

        //...
    }         
}
```

}

When the app is not run (or works in background) then the app is opened, as expected. I also get the onNewIntent event but in this case

```
 intent.Action == "android.nfc.action.MAIN"
```

and

```
intent.GetParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraNdefMessages);
```

returns null. Is it possible to get the orginal intent (with Tech or Tag discovered action) at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm note sure if that's the perfect solution for you.

What I do:

1.) Define the Activity with an Intent Filter on TECH_DISCOVERED

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.general.NFCActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

2.) Define the resource of the techs

```
<resources>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

3.) Work with the tag info

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)) {
                    byte[] id_array = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helped :)